# Updating Android WebView AppCache Settings for Modern Android Versions

Tags: android-13

I'm working on an Android application that uses a WebView to display web content. In the past, I used the following code to configure AppCache settings for the WebView:

However, I've recently learned that these methods have been deprecated and removed in newer Android versions (Android 12 and beyond). I want to update my code to use the recommended approach for managing caching in WebView.

Can someone please guide me on how to achieve the same caching functionality without using the deprecated setAppCachePath, setAppCacheMaxSize, and setAppCacheEnabled methods? I'd like to ensure my app is compatible with modern Android versions while maintaining proper caching for web content.

Any code examples or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
        webView.settings.setAppCachePath(appCachePath)
        webView.settings.setAppCacheMaxSize(1024 * 1024 * 8)
        webView.settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true)
```